# few empty spaces in start of csv file before header data by python

Tags: python, csv

In csv file if the line start with # sign or it is empty, I can remove or ignore it easily.

```
# some description here
# 1 is for good , 2 is bad and 3 for worse
empty line
```

I can deal by ignoring the empty line and line start with # by following logic in python.

```
while True:
    if len(data[0]) == 0 or data[0][0][0] == '#':
        data.pop(0)
    else:
        break
return data
```

But   Below is header data but it has few empty spaces in start and then data is available

```
            0 temp_data 1 temp_flow  2 temp_record 3 temp_all 
22            33            434           344
34            43            434           355
```

In some files i got header data like below and then I had to ignore only # sign and not column names

```
#0 temp_data 1 temp_flow  2 temp_record 3 temp_all 
22            33            434           344
34            43            434           355


But I get no clue how to deal with these two situation.
```

if someone help me. it would be grateful. because my above logic fails on these two situations.

Comment: can you edit your input file in order to have an idea about your cv file fileds ?

Comment: @nexus66 I really appreciate your help. .

Comment: Thanks. I updated my answer. test it and leave your feedbacks.

Comment: can you tell me which python version do you use ?

Comment: @nexus66 i am using Python 2.7.12

Comment: Well i double checked my last answer and my code works with Python 2.710 and python 3.4. If need only to copy paste it. otherwise i can't help you more. And i deleted my answer cause it don't fit with your needs.

Comment: @nexus66 but thanx for your time and help. .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string `strip()` function to remove leading and trailing whitespace first...

```
>>> '            0 temp_data 1 temp_flow  2 temp_record 3 temp_all'.strip()
'0 temp_data 1 temp_flow  2 temp_record 3 temp_all'
```

Comment: I know this function but it is not applicable here.